# Python File write, weird behaviour

Tags: python, file, readlines

Let's say I have this file:

```
abc
def
```

Then I do this:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r+') as f:
    f.write("FOO\n") 
    # f.readlines()
```

As expected, the file becomes:

```
FOO
def
```

But if I uncomment the `f.readlines()`, it instead becomes this:

```
abc
def
FOO
```

I could not find anything in documentation to explain this strange behaviour. Why is this happening? I do the `write` *before* the `readlines`.

Update. I would like to clarify my question:
Why in the first example new content is added to the BEGINNING of the file and in the second example it is added to the END of the file?

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcyxDsIgEIDhnae4tAMQTRcX4wO4mQ5dWaocKUk9CFyDfXo06uBQ//EfvrjyFOhwjKnWFgZkWCJYvAdwfkZRPE8QIpKSjJk7frDcgyxSw5jBnQS8cl1JnlHJ8XozZNEZklqIFi7Berf@Q9JuU2nOfW@o0fC9CUc7e8Ks3uYwhQIJ8zLzJvxLxuSJ1YdQWtf6BA)

Comment: They didn't (necessarily)- others have downvoted. But on further consideration, I'm not entirely sure why. My _guess_ is that you exhaust a file buffer but it's not so clear on what happens here

Comment: The problem arises because the write() has not been flushed to the stream. Add file.flush() before file.readlines() and note the difference in behaviour

Comment: @Pingu, file.flush(), file.seek(0) before file.readlines() does the trick. But if I replace file.readlines() with file.read(), file.flush() or any other calls are not needed. Everything works as expected. Can you explain this please? Does file.read() internally call file.flush() method?

Comment: @Abdulaziz the call to file.seek(0) is irrelevant unless you're going to write more data to the stream

Comment: @KellyBundy, why then in the first example it REPLACED the text at the BEGINNING of the file, and in the second example it is REPLACED the text at the END of the file? Can you explain this behaviour?

Comment: @KellyBundy, this is exactly what I'm talking about. Why is output different if you uncomment file.readlines() in #Modify example. It has nothing to do with file.write('FOO\n'). Or Am I missing something?

Comment: I can't find it documented, either. I replaced yours with my suggested MRE, as I think that improves the question. Roll back if you disagree.

Comment: @KellyBundy, you formulated the question much better. thanks.

Comment: “ Note that ANSI C requires that a file positioning
       function intervene between output and input, unless an input
       operation encounters end-of-file.  (If this condition is not met,
       then a read is allowed to return the result of writes other than
       the most recent.)” [ref](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html)

Comment: @MarkTolonen, this is the answer to the strange behaviour. Thanks.